# Java ProcessBuilder in Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, processbuilder

Basically I want to open a bash file in directory /home/linux/src
named i that is executable file in java using Netbeans..
When I press a button in Java file it will open the bash file..

```
Process p = null;
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("i");
pb.directory("/home/linux/src");
p = pb.start();
```

any idea ?

Comment: nope got error at pb.directory() string cannot be convert to file

Comment: "named i that is executable file in java using NetBeans"? What does this even mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a look at the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#directory%28java.io.File%29) you will see that ProcessBuilder  takes a File as a parameter not a String.

try

```
pb.directory(new File("/home/linux/src"));
```

Also

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("./i");
```

if `.` is not in you path (good idea)

Comment: still the same cannot open the bash file

Comment: can compile but still cant open the bash file 
  try {
            //try statement
            Process p = null;
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("i");
            pb.directory(new File("/home/linux/src"));
            p = pb.start();
            }
        catch (IOException e)
            {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error");     
            }

Comment: so is an exception thrown?  how do you know you can not open?

Comment: open up the Error message but not the bash file

Comment: so what is the Exception?  `e.printStackTrace ();`

Comment: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "i" (in directory "/home/linux/src"): error=2, No such file or directory
 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1042)
 at my.mainmenu.MainMenuUI.jButton1ActionPerformed(MainMenuUI.java:171)
 at my.mainmenu.MainMenuUI.access$000(MainMenuUI.java:18)
 at my.mainmenu.MainMenuUI$1.actionPerformed(MainMenuUI.java:64)

Comment: try `ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("./i");`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute a program using `ProcessBuilder`, you need to either pass it an absolute path, or make sure that the program is in your `PATH` environment variable. Calling `pb.directory("/path/to/program");` will not automatically make Java find your program (unless `.`, current directory, is in your `PATH`).

If you want to run a program `i` in `/home/linux/src` you should do

```
pb = new ProcessBuilder("/home/linux/src/i");
pb.start();
```

Note, however, that for this to work, `i` needs to be a script or an executable binary with the executable bit set (see `man chmod` for how to do this).